# Undefined port number as output - UDP/C/Linux

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, udp

I have defined the port number in both client as well as server program. I start the simple udp server program which receives packet from client. The server gets the packet But when i print the client information, Port number is know as Random number (51958) 
How to get the correct port number . i.e. the number i have defined.

```
  #define PORT XYZ
       ...
     if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
        diep("socket");

      memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));

      si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
      si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
      si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

      if(bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &si_me, sizeof(si_me)) == -1)
        diep("bind");

      for(i = 0; i < NPACK; i += 1) {
        if(recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen) == -1)
          diep("recvfrom()");

        printf("Recieved packet from %s: %d\nData: %s\n\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr), ntohs(si_other.sin_port), buf);
      }
      close(s);
```

///     client

```
   #define PORT XYZ

   if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
                diep("socket");

        memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));

        si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
        si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        if(inet_aton(SRV_IP, &si_other.sin_addr) == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        {
                for(i = 0; i < NPACK; i += 1) {
                        printf("Sending packet %d\n", index);
                        sprintf(buf, "This is packet%d\n", index);
                     ;
                        if(sendto(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen) == -1)
                                diep("sendto()");
                        index++;
                }

        }
        close(s);
```

**Update**
If we have data sent on N number of sockets and On the server side we are in a while(1) loop receiving the data , How do we identify the port the client has sent ?

Comment: You'll need to post the client code as well, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think *it actually is* the correct port number, since you're printing the source port of the client (the client host uses a random free one if not else specified) and not the destination port which is the one the server is listening too

If you have multiple sockets you can get the port which is bound to with [getsockname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getsockname.html)

```
if (getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &len) == -1)
    perror("getsockname");
else
    printf("port number of the listening socket %d\n", ntohs(sin.sin_port));
```

Comment: I have specified the port number in both client and server si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);

Comment: in client code you're setting the destination port of the message and not source one.

Comment: I'm under the impression that the fifth parameter of recvfrom() gets the client details.

Comment: it does! it contains source ip and port of the received packet. The destination port doesn't need to be specified because is binded to the socket you've just read that from (print ntohs(si_me.sin_port if you need to print it)

Comment: If i'm receiving data from multiple sockets how do identify the port that i have received the data.

Comment: every listening socket could be binded to just one port... so... if you know which socket you are recvfrom() with, then you know which is the destination port you're talking about

Comment: @m4n07 It doesn't 'get the client details.' It gets the *peer* details, where the datagram came from.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't bound the client socket to a specific port, so it gets a system-allocated port.